# I want to open a website using chrome web driver and python

Tags: python, webdriver

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

#Open browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url='https://www.premierleague.com/players'
driver.get(url)
```

This the code I have. It only opens for a second and then closes again. Does anyone know why?

I am assuming the problem is with the chrome driver manager, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time.sleep(10)` to keep the window open. I'm using 10 as an example for the number of seconds.